# Passing an array to a function. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a novice and am trying to pass a string into a function, or whatever.

Down below under data and items there is some text.

- "work history"
- "Projects"
- "Education"

This is a file called index.js.  A little further down is BubbleInfo.  What is the syntax to get my text into BubbleInfo so I can pass it to a function. Ive tried for days and days and can not get the correct syntax to grab the text. I always get an error or undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var bubbleChart = new d3.svg.BubbleChart({
    supportResponsive: true,
    //container: => use @default
    size: 600,
    //viewBoxSize: => use @default
    innerRadius: 600 / 3.5,
    //outerRadius: => use @default
    radiusMin: 50,
    //radiusMax: use @default
    //intersectDelta: use @default
    //intersectInc: use @default
    //circleColor: use @default

    data: {
      items: [
        {text: "Work History", count: "3"},
        {text: "Projects", count: "4"},
        {text: "Education", count: "3"},
        {text: "Work Locations", count: "4"},
      ],

      eval: function (item) {return item.count;},
      classed: function (item) {return item.text.split(" ").join("");}

    },

    plugins: [
      {
        name: "central-click",
        options: {
          text: ("See more detail"),
          BubbleInfo: (**data.items.text**),
          style: {
            "font-size": "12px",
            "font-style": "italic",
            "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
            //"font-weight": "700",
            "text-anchor": "middle",
            "fill": "white"
          },
          attr: {dy: "65px"},
           centralClick: function() {
  //          window.alert("Here is details!!");
          }
        }
      },
      {
        name: "lines",
        options: {
          format: [
            {// Line #0
              textField: "count",
              classed: {count: true},
              style: {
                "font-size": "28px",
                "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
                "text-anchor": "middle",
                fill: "white"
              },
              attr: {
                dy: "0px",
                x: function (d) {return d.cx;},
                y: function (d) {return d.cy;}
              }
            },
            {// Line #1
              textField: "text",
              classed: {text: true},
              style: {
                "font-size": "14px",
                "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
                "text-anchor": "middle",
                fill: "white"
              },
              attr: {
                dy: "20px",
                x: function (d) {return d.cx;},
                y: function (d) {return d.cy;}
              }
            }
          ],
          centralFormat: [
            {// Line #0
              style: {"font-size": "50px"},
              attr: {}
            },
            {// Line #1
              style: {"font-size": "30px"},
              attr: {dy: "40px"}
            }
          ]
        }
      }]
  });
});
```

Comment: So you want an array of all the text fields?

Comment: `data.items` is an array, to pass that array use ... wait for it .... `data.items`. The array contains 4 objects, to access the objects use `data.items[0]` for the first one, `data.items[1]` for the second one etc. then `data.items[0].text`. If you want all the text, you're going to have to change the array, or map it into something else.

Answer (score 0):

*If* I understood your question correctly and you simply want an array containing all the text fields, you can simply use `Array.prototype.map`.

```
var data = {
    items: [{
        text: "Work History",
        count: "3"
    }, {
        text: "Projects",
        count: "4"
    }, {
        text: "Education",
        count: "3"
    }, {
        text: "Work Locations",
        count: "4"
    }]
};
var texts = data.items.map(function(item) {
    return item.text;
}); //["Work History", "Projects", "Education", "Work Locations"]

var bubbleChart = new d3.svg.BubbleChart({
    ///...
    data: data, //Add methods to data declaration above if needed
    plugins: [{
        //...
        options: {
            BubbleInfo: texts
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: I get an error of unexpected identifier.  Is that because I have to put it somewhere else in the code. Where should I put that code where I dont get that error?

Comment: You can't expect anyone to magically know where you put something in your code if you don't show it. The same goes for resolving errors.

Comment: Sorry,  newbie here. my bad.  I was putting it right above the plugins:[ syntax from above.

Comment: You can't declare random variables there, you're in the middle of an object's definition.